# Will python multiprocessing.dummy.Pool switch to other process before it finish?

Tags: python

I'm using pool.map(func, iterable_obj) to run multiple subprocesses

In each function I set tqdm to monitor the progress, (so if Pool(3), I will see 3 progress bars)

but I found that it switched to other process in iterable_obj before it finished (The progress bar hasn't 100% yet)

I did write videos and .txt files in each function, is it because it's waiting I/O so the cpu switched to other process?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html): _multiprocessing.dummy replicates the API of multiprocessing but is no more than a wrapper around the threading module._ If you are using multiprocessing.dummy, you are not creating subprocesses.

Comment: If you aren't using dummy,  `map` will resolve the iterable to a list, divide it into chunks and pass those chunks to subprocesses. How to use tqdm in this scenario is a tricky business. I don't know where you got 3 status bars, unless you are looping in the worker function I guess?? But a minimal demo program would help clear things up. tqdm with multiprocessing is tricky. Usually you'd do something like imap_unordered and have a single status bar in the parent. If you try do to something in the worker, progress bars would tend to overwrite each other.

Comment: Yes, the tqdm is in the function

Comment: Does is mean multiprocessing.dummy is like a simulation of Pool for multithread?

Comment: Yes, it is just done with threads.

Comment: Thank you! so the reason why it switched is because it is thread?